# Weird behavior of consumer group rebalance due to increase in partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 2 Observations wrt consumer group rebalancing.

**Observation 1 -**
I have multiple consumers on the same group , each subscribed to different topics. The entire Consumer group rebalance is expected to happen when I increase partition count for a topic. But I'm not observing this. The newly created partitions are never automatically assigned to the existing consumer. For them to be assigned I have to recreate the consumers again.

**Observation 2 -**
I have a single consumer in a consumer group and this consumer is only subscribed to 1 topic. When I increase partition count on that topic, I am observing a rebalance within a couple of minutes.

Can anyone help me identify the problem here? I'm guessing that having multiple consumers subscribed to different topics is the issue here. Is my understanding right? Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Consumers will do metadata refreshes on a periodic interval. Perhaps your second observation just happened to do the refresh immediately.

Comment: I waited for a long time. I had both the groups up at the same time as well. One was happening and the other wasn't.

Comment: To clarify, you are using the same group across both "observations"? And both are "up at the same time"? If so, then  yes, only a subset of consumers (up to the original partition count) will be actively trying to consume until the [`metadata.max.age.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_metadata.max.age.ms) is reached